# Catalina apache 2.4.41 http://localhost/~username The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: apache2.4, macos-catalina, mod-userdir

```
% whoami
tim.daley
% % apachectl -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Unix)
Server built:   Oct  1 2019 10:31:38
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:88
Server loaded:  APR 1.7.0, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
Compiled using: APR 1.7.0, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.4.41_1"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/usr/local/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/usr/local/etc/httpd/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf"
% uname -a
Darwin Tims-MacBook-Pro-2.local 19.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.3.0: Thu Jan  9 20:58:23 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.81.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: (with comments and blank lines removed)

```
ServerRoot "/usr"
<IfDefine SERVER_APP_HAS_DEFAULT_PORTS>
    Listen 8080
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !SERVER_APP_HAS_DEFAULT_PORTS>
    Listen 80
</IfDefine>
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module libexec/apache2/mod_mpm_prefork.so
LoadModule authn_file_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module libexec/apache2/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module libexec/apache2/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule include_module libexec/apache2/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module libexec/apache2/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module libexec/apache2/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module libexec/apache2/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module libexec/apache2/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module libexec/apache2/mod_version.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module libexec/apache2/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule unixd_module libexec/apache2/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module libexec/apache2/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module libexec/apache2/mod_autoindex.so
<IfModule !mpm_prefork_module>
    #LoadModule cgid_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgid.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so
</IfModule>
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module libexec/apache2/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module libexec/apache2/mod_dir.so
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
LoadModule hfs_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_hfs_apple.so
<IfModule unixd_module>
User _www
Group _www
</IfModule>
ServerAdmin you@example.com
ServerName Tims-MacBook-Pro-2.local:80
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews Indexes
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "^\.([Hh][Tt]|[Dd][Ss]_[Ss])">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
<Files "rsrc">
    Require all denied
</Files>
<DirectoryMatch ".*\.\.namedfork">
    Require all denied
</DirectoryMatch>
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
LogLevel trace8
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log" common
</IfModule>
<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAliasMatch ^/cgi-bin/((?!(?i:webobjects)).*$) "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/$1"
</IfModule>
<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /private/etc/apache2/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>
TraceEnable off
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf
```

/etc/apache2/users/tim.daley.conf:

```
<Directory "/Users/tim.daley/Sites/">
    AddLanguage en .en
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index index.html default.html default.htm
    AllowOverride All
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
    <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
    Require all granted
    </Limit>
    <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
    Require all denied
    </LimitExcept>
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AddHandler perl-script .pl
    PerlHandler ModPerl::Registry
</Directory>
```

/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf:

```
UserDir Sites
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
<IfModule bonjour_module>
       RegisterUserSite customized-users
</IfModule>
```

/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

% ls -al Sites
total 32
drwxrwxrwx    7 tim.daley  staff   224 Mar  5 12:07 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 202 tim.daley  staff  6464 Mar  6 11:31 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 tim.daley  staff   174 Mar  5 12:07 index.html
```

http://http://localhost/~tim.daley:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

I've checked all kinds of articles such as https://tech-cookbook.com/2019/10/07/setting-up-your-local-server-on-macos-catalina-2019-mamp/, https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-apache-mysql-php-on-macos-catalina-10-15, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300081/apache-not-working-with-user-sites-folder-on-macos-10-13-high-sierra.

Can anyone suggest what I can do to get this working?

Comment: You need to create another ‘VirtualHost’ on httpd-vhosts.conf. And adjust the DocumentRoot, serverName, and serverAlias based on the project that you are trying to run.

Comment: error_log entry that corresponds?